# Are these boundaries true?

Tags: integration

I want to find the double integral 
$$\iint xy \, dx\,dy $$ 
over the region
bounded by the positive $y$- axis, the line $y=\sqrt3 \ x$ and the circle
 $x^2+y^2=4$.

My solution is that  $x=0$ to $x=(1/\sqrt3) y$, and $y=0$ to $y=2$.
Is that correct?

Comment: No. That would be a triangle instead of a circular section.

Comment: could you explain?

Comment: You didn't consider the $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ boundary

Comment: your answer would be the region bounded by the lines $y = \sqrt{3}x$ and $y = 2$

Comment: I think the boundries $y=0$ to $y=2$ is ok but I have problem with the $x$ boundries

Answer (score 1):

By switching to polar coordinates, you integral is given by:

$$ \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{2}\rho^3\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\,d\rho\,d\theta=2\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2}\sin(2\theta)\,d\theta=\cos(2\pi/3)-\cos(\pi)=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

> My solution is that  $x=0$ to $x=(1/\sqrt3) y$, and $y=0$ to $y=2$.

If you express it in that kind of language, it would be best to be explicit that you're putting the integral with respect to $y$ on the outside.

This would be
$$
\int_0^2 \left( \int_0^{y/\sqrt 3} xy \, dx \right) \, dy
$$
and that is **not** correct.  It ignores the equation $x^2+y^2=4$.

If $x^2+y^2 = 4$ and $x\sqrt3 = y$, then $3x^2 + x^2 = 4$ then $x= \pm 1$.  Since you say the "positive" $y$-axis, we need $x=+1$.

The equation $y^2+x^2=4$, is equivalent to $y = \pm\sqrt{4-x^2}$, and conjoining that with $y\ge 0$ we have $y = \sqrt{4-x^2}$.

So we can say $x$ goes from $0$ up to $1/\sqrt3$, and then for any fixed value of $x$, the other variable $y$ goes from $x\sqrt3$ up to $\sqrt{4-x^2}$, so we have
$$
\int_0^1 \left( \int_{x\sqrt3}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} xy\, dy \right) \, dx
$$
(If there is any question about which of the two bounds on the inside integral is bigger, draw a picture.) **Details below.**

If you want to do it in the other order, then it's more complicated.  You'd have
$$
\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^{y/\sqrt3} xy \, dx \right) \, dy + \int_1^2 \left( \int_0^{\sqrt{4-y^2}} xy \, dx \right) \, dy.
$$

In order to actually *evaluate* the integral, I would not do it like this; I would use polar coordinates.

**Details:** We have $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \left( \int_{x\sqrt3}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} xy\, dy \right) \, dx$.  The inside integral is $$\int_{x\sqrt3}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} xy \, dy = \left[ \frac{xy^2} 2 \right]_{y:=x\sqrt3}^{y:=\sqrt{4-x^2}}$$ $$= \frac{x(4-x^2)} 2 - \frac{x\cdot 3x^2} 2 = 2x - 2x^3.$$ Then the outside integral becomes

$$ \int_0^1 \left( 2x - 2x^3 \right) \, dx = \left[ x^2 - \frac{x^4} 2 \right]_0^1 = \frac 1 2$$

**But** (as I said above) **this is not how I would normally do this.  I would use polar coordinates.**

Comment: Michael Hardy, thank you for your answer, but the result for both ways are different and not equals (0.5) which supposed to be the right result.

Comment: @adam : I was hasty about some details.  I've fixed it.  The two methods yield the same result.  But as I said, I would use polar coordinates.  This integral begs for those. ${}\qquad{}$